# Can  mean "Calm, self-possessed waiting"?

Tags: vocabulary

[*Patientia*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=la&l=patientia#lexicon) come from *passio* (to suffer, bear); it means the ability to bear suffering. But can *patientia* in Latin also mean "Calm, self-possessed waiting" ([*OED*'s sense 1c](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/138816#eid31766406))?

Answer (score 3):

Yes – or at least something very close to that – but it is apparently a rare usage, at least in ancient Latin. I did not find unequivocal examples in Lewis & Short or Georges, and [Forcellini](http://lexica.linguax.com/forc2.php?searchedLG=patientia) does not even mention this sense.

<sup>Quamquam Aegidius Forcellini *patientiam* ita definit: «actus et habitus perpetiendi incommoda et mala», quod, si exspectandi diuturnitatem incommodum quoddam, quin etiam malum ducimus, tuam significationem complectitur.</sup>

But the [Thesaurus Linguae Latinae](https://publikationen.badw.de/de/thesaurus/-/10,1.713.jpg) is more explicit and has this to say:

> **C** de -a potius eorum, qui *non praepropere agunt* vel aliquid *futurum fideliter exspectant* [⋯] **2** *speciatim* in religione iud. et *christ.* de exspectatione *iudicii divini* vel *regni dei* [⋯]

See the link for attestations. So I would say you can use *patientia* in that sense with a clean conscience – praesertim cum aptius verbum Latinum non facile invenies.